# Time difference between two iso timestamps using shell

Tags: shell

I am looking for shell command which can help me to get difference between two timestamps that are in this format - `2021-07-28T19:18:02+00:00`. I am able to achieve this in python, but need to handle this in shell. I am trying to strip the H:M:S part from the timestamp and then getting the difference. But it is issuing an error in below code.

```
echo $EndTime
1970-01-01T01:08:26+00:00    
curr=$(date -d "${EndTime}" +"%H:%M:%S")
date: invalid date '1970-01-01T01:08:26+00:00'
```

I want to get 01:08:26 from the above timestamp.

Comment: `date -d 1970-01-01T01:08:26+00:00` works fine in my shell. What is your `locale`? Try `LC_ALL=C date ....`

Comment: LC_ALL=C date
Fri Aug 19 23:29:45 -05 2022   Is this the issue? Should I convert the given timestamp in the locale? in order to make the script work?

Comment: I do not understand your comment. `s this the issue?` I do not know what "this" refers to. `the given timestamp in the locale?` No idea, that's what I am suggesting to invstigate. Please post the output of `locale` on your system. What is the output of `LC_ALL=C date -d 1970-01-01T01:08:26+00:00`?

Comment: The final `+00:00` causes an issue on openSUSE 15.4, e.g. `date -d "1970-01-01T01:08:26+00:00"` yields `Wed 31 Dec 1969 07:08:26 PM CST` (pre-epoch), but removing the `+00:00` works fine yielding `Thu 01 Jan 1970 01:08:26 AM CST`. Which means the `+00:00` offset forces my local computer to be considered as zulu time instead of -5 CDT.

Comment: ok so after configuring the locale, I now see the command working, but it is still extracting a different time. The output of the program I posted in the main thread shows the value as 17:08:26  instead of 01:08:26.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a tool called [dateutils](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/dateutils.dateutils.1.html) to calculate the date diff:

```
$ sudo apt install dateutils

$ dateutils.ddiff -f %S 1970-01-01T01:08:26+00:00 2021-07-28T19:18:02+00:00
1627495776
```